# Unknown column 'discussion.rubric_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, triggers

I needed to rename a few of my MySQL tables and thereby messed up my procedures. At least that's what I think... I am getting an error that wasn't there before.

Two tables are important: One is called `rubrics` and it has a column to count the `discussions` that are related to the `rubric`. So whenever a new `discussion` gets inserted, a `procedure` gets triggered that increments the *counter*.

These are the two tables (in short):

this is my **rubric** table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rubric` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `topic_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
    `description` TEXT NULL ,
    `total_discussions` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,  // this is the COUNTER
    `latest_activity_id` INT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `topic_id`) ,
... // just some index and constraint..
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is my **discussions** table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discussion` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `rubric_id` INT NOT NULL ,       // as you can see it has a rubric_id column
    `topic_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `latest_activity_id` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
    `description` TEXT NULL ,
    `total_posts` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    `total_views` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `rubric_id`, `topic_id`) ,
    ... // just some index and constraint..
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here is the **procedure** that should increment the *counter* in the *rubrics* table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER count_discussions AFTER INSERT ON discussion
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE rubric SET total_discussions = total_discussions + 1 WHERE rubric.id = discussion.rubric_id;
END $$
```

The error I am getting when inserting a new row is:

```
Error code 1054, SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'discussion.rubric_id' in 'where clause'
```

So I am guessing that it is about the *WHERE clause* of the *procedure* because, I have no other *WHERE clause* that mentions the *rubric_id* column. But as you can see in the discussions table, the column exists. So is it a typo or some syntax I don't respect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
   DELIMITER $$

   CREATE TRIGGER count_discussions AFTER INSERT ON discussion
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   UPDATE rubric 
   INNER JOIN discussion ON rubric.id =   discussion.rubric_id 
   SET total_discussions = total_discussions + 1 ;
   END $$
```

you need to join the table discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that quick and working answer. Didn't know I could JOIN in a trigger! It is working now, although I am still wondering why it worked before renaming the tables ... thank you!